# spreadsheet import excel to array timeout

Tags: php, spreadsheet, kint

I have written a piece of code that turns into array an excel that a user uploads.
on 5/10 rows works totally fine but if i try to upload a bigger file ( not that big, something like 150 rows X 8 columns) i get a timeout error.

```
    $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
    $reader->setReadDataOnly(true);

    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);

    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getSheet($spreadsheet->getFirstSheetIndex());
    $data = $sheet->toArray();
```

what am i doing wrong?

The error message

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\testversion\vendor\kint-php\kint\src\Object\Blob.php on line 72

Comment: ___get a timeout error.___ Can we see the error please. Always show any error message, in their entirety, no summarisation please

Comment: sure, here it is:
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\testversion\vendor\kint-php\kint\src\Object\Blob.php on line 72

Comment: And which of the 5 lines of code you show is line 72 and is this the code in `Blob.php`

Comment: public static function detectEncoding($string){
        if (function_exists('mb_detect_encoding')){
            return mb_detect_encoding($string, self::$char_encodings, true); 
        }

        if (!function_exists('iconv')){
            return 'UTF-8';
        }

        $md5 = md5($string);
        foreach (self::$char_encodings as $encoding){
            // fuck knows why, //IGNORE and //TRANSLIT still throw notice
            if (md5(@iconv($encoding, $encoding, $string)) === $md5) {
                return $encoding;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

Comment: no. blob.php is a file containing some of the function being called. the error is at the first return

Comment: Do you see the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71464885/edit) link under the Question box. You should use that to add to or amend your question as you service our requests for more information! Because nobody can read code in a comment

Comment: my bad, still new to stackoverflow. Anyway i managed to resolve the problem, it was the excel file itself, i casually copy-pasted everything on a brand new file and every thing worked out fine.

ty for your assistance anyway!